# jquery ui memory leak and video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, memory-leaks

i have met some strange behaviour. when i have a page with a video-tag and create afterwards a jquery ui element dynamically, chrome-dev-tools shows me in the timeline view a memory leak, everytime i create (and destroy the element afterwards). it`s tested with ui - button and ui - dialog so far. when i remove the source of the video tag, the leak doesn`t show up. does anyone has an idea? thanks a lot.

i created it also here for testing purpose: http://jsfiddle.net/2P8Eh/

thanks a lot for your answers. i just realized that testing with jsfiddle gives me different results when testing lokal (i guess it`s because of the iframe, where they running the code). anyway i considerd your solutions, but they don`t solve the memory-leak problem. i attached an image, where i created, destroyed, created, destroyed... the element and put afterwards the gc button in chrome-dev:

[image: http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/leakfvlr7jxu4q.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Id must be unique .

you add element with same id.

---

Id is unique so as the browser find the first element with that id it add styles to that element and rest elements are ignored. As id must be unique so it never looks for another element with same id.

---

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

---

Update after OP's comment

<kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/xAcfr/)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    $("#btn-destroy").prop('disabled', true);//disable destroy
    $("#btn-create").click(function () {
        $("body").append("<div id='new-button'>test</div>");
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);// disable create button
        $("#btn-destroy").prop('disabled', false);// enable destroy button
        $("#new-button").button();
    });
    $("#btn-destroy").click(function () {
        $("#new-button").button("destroy").remove();
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);// disable destroy button
        $("#btn-create").prop('disabled', false);// enable create button
    });
});
```

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. i mean when i create the element and destroy/remove it afterwards and create it again. the buttons in the example should be clicked one after the other not one two times in a row. so the id is always unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to add multiple elements and remove them all at once, then use class instead of ID. The same command will be applied to all elements that has that class.

```
(function() {   
            $( "#btn-create" ).click(function() {
                $( "body" ).append("<div class='new-button'>test</div>");
                buttons.push(buttons.pull()+1)
                $( ".new-button" ).button();
            });
            $( "#btn-destroy" ).click(function() {
                $( ".new-button" ).button("destroy").remove();
            });
        });
```

If you want to add elements and remove them by reverse order of the their creation, then keep track of the unique id identified in an array for example. Notice here the element ID must be unique in the whole DOM. If two elements have the same ID, then most likely JQuery will only find the first one and you might get unexpected behavior.

```
$(function() {
    var buttons_id = [1]; 
            $( "#btn-create" ).click(function() {  
                buttons_id.push(Number(buttons_id.length-1)+1);
                var id =  buttons_id[buttons_id.length-1];           
                console.log("first id="+id);
                var id_str = "new-button"+id;           
                $( "body" ).append("<div class='"+id_str+"'>test</div>");              
                $( "."+id_str).button();
            });
            $( "#btn-destroy" ).click(function() {
                var id =   buttons_id.pop(); 
                console.log("poped id = "+id);
                $( ".new-button"+id ).button("destroy").remove();
            });
        });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2P8Eh/1/)

Comment: Oh crabs, now the OP has added more details to his question.